# How to get php id associate with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So I am developing a library management system where I want to Preview bookpdf from the database by its id. How to link the bookid with a different preview button. The below code which I have done is opening just the location of the folder where the books are stored. How to link PHP id with javascript/jquery? I am a beginner and can't figure out how to solve it. I have attached an image of my search page.

```
 <?php
    $count=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        if($count==0)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
        }
        
        echo '<td width="20%" align="center" style="font-size: 16px;">      
            <br>'.$row['BookName'].'</a>
            <br>';?>
            <button class="btn btn-danger basic-demo_button" data-target="#ab<?php echo $row['bookid']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Preview</button>                                          

</div>  
        
        <?php
        $count++;                           
        
        if($count==4)
        {
            echo '</tr>';
            $count=0;
        }
    }

?>
```

The button is in the while loop, and the div to get the PDF version of the book is outside the while loop but it's not getting the corresponding book. It's just going to the folder where the book is stored.

```
 <div id="ab<?php echo $row['bookid'];?>" class="example_content basic-demo"><?php echo '
        <embed src="assets/img/'.$row['BookSummary'].'" height="750px" width="1476.670px" />'?></div>
```

And below is my script code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/popupwindow.js"></script>
<script>

var Demo = (function($, undefined){

  $(function(){
        QuickDemo();
    });
  function QuickDemo(button){
        $(".basic-demo").PopupWindow({
            autoOpen    : false,
            nativeDrag: false
        });
        $(".basic-demo_button").on("click", function(event){
            $(".basic-demo").PopupWindow("open");
        });
    }
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Please go and enable proper PHP error reporting first of all, that surely should have something to tell you here.

Comment: `<div id="ab<?php echo $row['bookid'];?>" …><?php echo '
        <embed src="assets/img/'.$row['BookSummary'].'" …` – if you have this _after_ the loop, then those values won’t exist. Your while loop ended, because `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returned NULL after the last record, so `$row` _is_ now NULL.

Comment: I understand. But if i put it inside the loop it opens up all the books no matter which button I have clicked.

Comment: Hi, onclick of button get data-target value and then use same to show particular pop .i.e `var targets = $(this).attr('data-target')` inside `$(".basic-demo_button").on("click", function(event){..` and then use `$( targets).PopupWindow("open");`